# Finding the closest target in a group of enemies with 3 different tags

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tags, targeting

I have a two-sided game, where turrets need to find the closest targets with specific tags.

LeftPlayer has 3 tags for 3 different enemy types.
RightPlayer has 3 tags for 3 different enemy types.
So a total of 6 tags, 3 for each Player.

Currently I'm using the FindClosestTarget method from Udemy's RealmRush course, which works almost right, but sadly both side's turrets target all 6 enemy types. That is why I'm trying to find a solution that uses tags.

I can give example of the forementioned Udemy RealmRush method, which might be salvagable and split into separate scripts for each side, but I don't know how to do so. The script also contains my commented out failed attempt at making it tag-based. Wherever I looked for solutions, I've only found examples for one tag, which also refuses to work. If you think that can be saved easier than the current version, I'm more than happy to do just that.

```
using Vector3 = UnityEngine.Vector3;

public class TargetLocator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform weapon;
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem projectileParticles;
    [SerializeField] float range = 1.5f;
    [SerializeField] Transform enemy;
    
    //public GameObject Target;
    public float maxDistance;

    void Update()
    {
        /*Target = FindClosestEnemy();

        range = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Target.transform.position);

        if (maxDistance < range)
        {
            FindClosestEnemy();
        }*/

        FindClosestTarget();
        AimWeapon();
    }

    /*public GameObject FindClosestEnemy()
    {
        Enemy[] enemies;
        enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("LeftBrute");
        GameObject closest;
        float maxDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        
        foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)
        {
            Vector3 diff = enemy.transform.position - position;
            float currentDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
            if (currentDistance < maxDistance)
            {
                closest = Target;
                maxDistance = currentDistance;
            }
        }

        return Target;
    }*/

    void FindClosestTarget()
    {
        Enemy[] enemies = FindObjectsOfType<Enemy>();
        Transform closestTarget = null;
        float maxDistance = Mathf.Infinity;

        foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)
        {
            float targetDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, enemy.transform.position);

            if (targetDistance < maxDistance)
            {
                closestTarget = enemy.transform;
                maxDistance = targetDistance;
            }
        }

        enemy = closestTarget;
    }

    public void AimWeapon()
    {
        float maxDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, enemy.transform.position);

        if (maxDistance < range)
        {
            weapon.LookAt(enemy.transform.position);
            Attack(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Attack(false);
            Debug.Log("Target not found");
        }
    }

    public void Attack(bool isActive)
    {
        var emissionModule = projectileParticles.emission;
        emissionModule.enabled = isActive;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you check for the tags in your code ...

Comment: As mentioned in the post, it is in the commented out part. It reads as enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("LeftBrute");
Or what do you mean?

Comment: But do I understand you wrong or doesn't anyway one turret only follow one tag? Why do you need all three tags in one script?

Comment: Because there can be 3 potential target types (tags) for the turret on the map at any given time. I want the TargetLocator script to handle those 3 tags as one group, then always target the one, that is the closest to the turret.

Since I have two sides, that should be handled separately (LeftPlayer and RightPlayer), I can't use Udemy's method, which completely ignores which tag belongs to which Player as it isn't using any tags.

Since I couldn't find anything remotely similar to what I need, I came here for help.
Please let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not entirely clear why different tags should be used for all types of enemies. It would be better to use inheritance or interfaces, but, according to your request - if you want to use a search by three different tags in the method - then implement a search by three tags in it.

```
public void FindClosestEnemy()
    {
        List<GameObject> nearestEnemies = new List<GameObject>();
        GameObject lastAddedEnemy = null;
        GameObject enemyTemp = null;

        float maxDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
        Vector3 position = transform.position;

        enemyTemp = FindNearestWithTag("LeftBrute_1"); // your tag name
        if (enemyTemp != null && enemyTemp != lastAddedEnemy)
        {
            nearestEnemies.Add(enemyTemp);
            lastAddedEnemy = enemyTemp;
        }

        enemyTemp = FindNearestWithTag("LeftBrute_2"); // your tag name
        if (enemyTemp != null && enemyTemp != lastAddedEnemy)
        {
            nearestEnemies.Add(enemyTemp);
            lastAddedEnemy = enemyTemp;
        }

        enemyTemp = FindNearestWithTag("LeftBrute_3"); // your tag name
        if (enemyTemp != null && enemyTemp != lastAddedEnemy)
        {
            nearestEnemies.Add(enemyTemp);
            lastAddedEnemy = enemyTemp;
        }

        foreach (var enemy in nearestEnemies)
        {
            Vector3 diff = enemy.transform.position - position;
            float currentDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
            if (currentDistance < maxDistance)
            {
                enemyTemp = enemy;
                maxDistance = currentDistance;
            }
        }

        Target = enemyTemp;
    }

    private GameObject FindNearestWithTag(string tagName)
    {
        GameObject[] enemies;
        enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(tagName);
        GameObject closest = null;
        float maxDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
        Vector3 position = transform.position;

        foreach (var enemy in enemies)
        {
            Vector3 diff = enemy.transform.position - position;
            float currentDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
            if (currentDistance < maxDistance)
            {
                closest = enemy;
                maxDistance = currentDistance;
            }
        }

        return closest;
    }
```

Comment: This works PERFECTLY! Thank you so much! I'm kinda new to programming with my whole 2 weeks of experience, but I learn from every mistake and question, so you really helped me out with this one. :)

The reason behind using individual tags for each enemy type is simply to let the currency system know if certain enemies did certain things. I found tags the easiest way of doing that, and it worked flawlessly. Sadly this meant that I should use a similar approach for this, but unlike the method I used for the currency system, I couldn't figure this one out on my own.

Thank you, once again!